# How can I fix {:multiple => true} causing undefined method stringify_keys for nil:NilClass?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to create check boxes that will return an array of tag_ids so that I can search by them. In order to do this I think that I need to include {:multiple => true} to the check box but I am not certain as I am pretty new to Ruby on Rails. I am not sure why this causing this error to occur, but when I remove this chunk of code the error goes away. What do I need to include to make this work, or do I need to think of a different solution? Let me know if I need to include more code if what I have included isn't enough.

(note: this code is not functional yet, just trying to fix this error)

applist.erb:

```
   <h2 class="ml-5">Categories</h2>
      <% tags = Tag.all %>
      <%= form_tag("../welcome/tagsearch", :method => "get") do%>
        <% tags.each{|tag| %>
          <div class="form-check ml-2">
            <%= check_box_tag :tag_ids, {:multiple => true}, tag.id, nil%>
            <label class="form-check-label"> <%= tag.name %></label>
          </div>
        <% } %>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-btn ml-1">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <%= button_tag(:class => 'btn btn-dark',:name => nil) do%>
                Submit
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
```

Error:
undefined method `stringify_keys' for nil:NilClass

Comment: On a side note, I would suggest the recommend `do end` syntax for your multi-line ERB so instead of ` <% tags.each{|tag| %><% } %>`  you would do ` <% tags.each do|tag| %> your multi lines then <% end %>

Comment: The reason this does not work is because your arguments do not match the method signature `check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})` I think you may have accidentally looked at `check_box` which is a form helper `check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")` in this case if called on the form object e.g. `f.checkbox` then your signature was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the error, I ended up doing the following:

```
<%= check_box_tag "tag_ids[]", tag.id, false, :id => "tag_ids_#{tag.id}" %>
```

instead of doing the multiple => true this works instead.